# Ubuntu 22.04 guest on Windows 10 VirtualBox host - no internet

Tags: virtualbox, 22.04

I have an Ubuntu 22.04 as a guest (type Ubuntu64) on a VirtualBox windows host. I have tried a bridged adapter. No internet connection. Everything that I have read says that I should have such a connection.
It is worth noting that if I build a VirtualBox guest with the said 22.04 .iso using an Oracle64 type in VirtualBox, I do get internet connection - very odd.
I am using VirtualBox Version 6.1.38 r153438 (Qt5.6.2) and the 22.04 Ubuntu desktop iso file downloaded from the Ubuntu site.
Does anyone have an answer to this strange issue? I would rather use the Ubuntu64 type in VirtualBox than the Oracle64 type, (I have snap issues with the Oracle64 type).

Internet is a private network at home, behind a personal router (ASUS). NAT does not work here but it does at work on the office network.

Comment: Use NAT instead of bridge. Bridge won't work in some cases. But you gave no information at all about your "internet connection".